# Opening mysql connection threw an exception in net core

Tags: mysql, .net-core, connection-string, connection-pooling

Im trying to open a connection just closed to mysql, this threw a exception totally misleading: "The given key was not present in the dictionary" my code can be summarized so:

```
  try
  {
     using var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
     await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
     using var selectCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
     selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM `objects.property` WHERE id=@id";
     selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
     using var reader = await selectCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
     flag = reader.HasRows;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     // log here
  }
  // try to reopen to create or update on table based on boolena variable flag 
  using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
  {
   await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
   using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "CREATE "; // create or update query here based on boolean variable flag
   await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
```

Sometimes an error will be catched, when i open first time the connection and sometimes when i reopen it, it seems me related to connection lifetime of mysql but not uderstand well how fix that, i tried also to create a single block of code and not close and reopen connection but in this case mysql tell me that connection in already in use: "connection already open error".
So how fix that? I also putted a check if connection state is already open before to open it in similar fashion:

```
  if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
     {
        // connection opened dont reopen it               
     }
```

the previuos code tell me that connection is always closed, but still i have random error , sometimes work and sometimes dont.
Im using net core 6 and mysql connector 2.2.7 and also I have updated latter to last 2.3.0-beta.3 version the most recent version at this time.